# Laravel 4.2 data query (daily, mothly, semi-annual, annual) pass to chart (view)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, highcharts

I'm trying to retrieve data from my database based on daily,monthly,semi-annual and annual then pass it to my chart(views). I'm using Highcharts, see: [www.highcharts.com](http://www.highcharts.com). My problem is that how can I group/count total number of username where "is_approved = 1". Only who are approved will be counted and pass the result to my views/chart.

*This is my table:* **Walker**

```
+------------------+------------------------------------+------+-----+----------
-----------+----------------+
| Field            | Type                               | Null | Key | Default
           | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------------------------+------+-----+----------
-----------+----------------+
| id               | int(10) unsigned                   | NO   | PRI | NULL
           | auto_increment |
| first_name       | varchar(255)                       | NO   | MUL | NULL
           |                |
| address          | varchar(255)                       | NO   |     | NULL
           |                |
| created_at       | timestamp                          | NO   |     | 0000-00-0
0 00:00:00 |                |
           |                |
| is_approved      | int(11)                            | NO   |     | NULL
           |                |
+------------------+------------------------------------+------+-----+----------
```

So far here what I've done, but I don't know how can I code it by daily, monthly, semi-annual, annual.

*This is my Controller codes:* **AdminController.php**

```
$walkers_cnt = Walker::where('is_approved','=','1')->count();
   return View::make('dashboard')
   ->with('title', $title)
   ->with('page', 'dashboard')
   ->with('walkers_cnt', $walkers_cnt)
```

In my views, by using highchart codes given I want to render those queried data (daily,monthly,semi-annual,annual) from my database and rendered it through tabs.

*This is my Views codes:* **dashboard.blade.php**

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Monthly App Users'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ],
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total number of Drivers/Users'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y}</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Drivers',
            data: [49, 71, 106, 129, 144, 176, 135, 148, 216, 194, 95, 54]

        }, {
            name: 'Users',
            data: [83, 78, 98, 9, 106, 84, 105, 104, 91, 83, 106, 92]

        }]
    });
    });

<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Hopefully you can help me about this, I don't know how can I do it to laravel 4.2 in most simple way. Thanks in advance. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 4.2 How to populate Highcharts (daily,monthly,semi-annual and annual basis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658157/laravel-4-2-how-to-populate-highcharts-daily-monthly-semi-annual-and-annual-bas)

Comment: Do you have any problems with Highcharts or are you just trying to import data using laravel?

Comment: Yes, I would like to import data using laravel and render it to my chart. Sorry for duplicated post Sir :(